# ASP.NET MVC redirect actions error with 'create' partial view on 'index' page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem with partial views.  I have an index view of Announcements and I'm trying to add a partial view to create a new Announcement within the same page.

I can display the partial view, and submit the form to create a new record.  The record gets submitted into the database, but when re-rendering the page, I get the error:  Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper', {"Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."} on my Html.Action statement in my index page.

I've been struggling to make this work, and have firstly changed the Html.Partial to a Html.Action statement as the controller methods weren't firing, then secondly, after I read that this error is because while rendering the page, .NET doesn't know what my redirect action is doing so automatically stops it, tried changing the Html.Action to Html.RedirectAction inside a code block, but still get the same error detailed above.

My model is quite simple:

```
public class Announcement
{
    public Announcement()
    {
        AnnouncementDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    public int AnnouncementID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller methods:

```
public ViewResult Index(string searchString, int? page)
    {
        var Announcements = from a in db.Announcements
                        select a;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            Announcements = Announcements.Where(s => (s.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || s.AnnouncementText.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())));
        }
        Announcements = Announcements.OrderBy(s => s.Title);

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        return View(Announcements.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

    //
    // GET: /Announcement/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Announcement announcement = new Announcement();

        return PartialView(announcement);       
    }

    //
    // POST: /Announcement/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Announcement announcement)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Announcements.Add(announcement);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
        } 

        return View(announcement);
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Project.Models.Announcement>     
@using PagedList.Mvc;   
@using PagedList;

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "search-query", placeholder = "Search by name" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
}
@item.Title
@item.Type
@Html.Action("Create"); // This is the line causing errors after I submit the Create form.  Have tried changing to Html.RedirectAction
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@model Project.Models.Announcement

@using (Html.BeginForm())   
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @style = "width:250px" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type, new { @style = "width:250px" })

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-small" />        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some testing locally...

**You can keep**

`@Html.Action("Create")`

**However**, you have to change one small thing. Define what action the POST points to in your form :)

```
@model Project.Models.Announcement

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create"))   
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @style = "width:250px" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type, new { @style = "width:250px" })

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-small" />        
}
```

Comment: My next problem is now that a search form on the Index page is posting into my Create page - are you able to help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390588/asp-net-index-page-with-search-posting-into-partial-view?